# What is expected date format in Upwork GraphQL API?

Tags: graphql, upwork-api

Im trying to access Time Report via Upwork GraphQL API using this query:

```
query {
  timeReport(filter: { organizationId_eq: "12345679", timeReportDate_bt: { rangeStart: "2023-11-01", rangeEnd: "2023-11-02" } }) {
    dateWorkedOn
    task
    taskDescription
    totalHoursWorked
  }
}
```

Upwork returns me an error: "2023-11-01 date could not be parsed".

I already tried different date and datetime formats, YYYY-MM-DD, MM/DD/YYYY, ISO, Unix timestamp - every time error message is the same, it can't parse the date.

[Upworks' documentation](https://www.upwork.com/developer/documentation/graphql/api/docs/index.html#definition-DateTimeRange) isn't helpfull at all:

```
{
  "rangeStart": "xyz789",
  "rangeEnd": "xyz789"
}
```

Can someone suggest, which date format is expected by Upwork GraphQL API?

Comment: I'm getting the impression they hired someone from Upwork to build Upwork's API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a week of waiting, I got an answer from Upwork support on my ticket:

> a format that has been used internally is "20231214" (without dashes).

I tested it, and it works. Overall, Upwork GraphQL API documentation is incomplete and outdated. Much more useful is their [GraphQL Explorer tool](https://www.upwork.com/developer/explorer/) which allows you to view schema and test your requests.